# Tunneling SSH over Shadowsocks

Tags: ssh, tunneling, shadowsocks

[This post on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416010/ssh-through-shadowsocks) explains how to tunnel SSH over [shadowsocks](https://shadowsocks.org).

[This post on sec.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135157/is-shadowsocks-mitm-able) discusses some of the vulnerabilities of shadowsocks (namely its vulnerability to brute force).

After reading through the [shadowsocks protocol](https://shadowsocks.org/en/spec/Protocol.html) and doing a quick overview of the [code base](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/tree/master)  it seems that tunneling SSH over shadowsocks would provide a means of bypassing stateful packet inspection (shadowsocks) while still maintaining a decent level of security (OpenSSH).

For example:

```
# ~/.bashrc 
export http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 
export https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 
export SOCKS5_PASSWORD=<superstrongpassword>

# ~/.ssh/config 
Host <hostname alias>
 HostName <ip or domain name>
 User <user>
 IdentityFile <path to ssh key>
 ProxyCommand connect -S 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p
```

Is this a sound assumption or would using them together like this expose a vulnerability that I missed?

If someone was able to brute force the shadowsocks `<superstrongpassword>` would they have any access to my box beyond just using it as a proxy?

Note: I am also reading through the [connect-proxy](https://github.com/larryhou/connect-proxy) code now. If anyone knows of any issues with that I would be interested.

Comment: I know this is example code, but want to mention that in real code you should not store your password in clear text.

Comment: @NeilSmithline agreed ... however I dont really care about the encryption or security provided by shadowsocks.  Just using it to get past the FW.  SSH and pubkey auth is what I am depending on for security.  shadowsocks password is just a randomly generated string in my case.  As a general rule of thumb I would agree with you though.